# Is an accordian list possible in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu

I am looking to set up a home page for our group in SharePoint that essentially has four areas. I kind of foresee four columns of accordion menus. The problem is that not all the items under the drop down will have web page links.

Is this possible to do? Is it possible to add icons at the top of each column to represent what the areas are? I am pretty new to SharePoint design and am taking a class but my boss is wanting something like this done to make it more user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefere to use the jQuery or another JavaScript driven accordeon to solve your problem. You can fetch you item the through SharePoint REST API or JSOM.

There are also a lot of examples out there but too long to copy in here:

[HOW TO CREATE DYNAMIC ACCORDIONS IN SHAREPOINT PAGES](http://summit7systems.com/how-to-create-dynamic-accordions-in-sharepoint-pages/)

[CSR code samples #6 (Accordion)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-ccdb2a0e)

[Customize the rendering of a List View in Sharepoint 2013: Displaying List Items in Accordion](https://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/14/customize-the-rendering-of-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-2013-displaying-list-items-in-accordion/)